# Deploy Spring Boot app to Heroku with a particular application.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku, deployment

I want to define different `application.properties` file for each environment. 
When working locally, I want to define a H2 database. For test environment (Heroku) I have a MySQL database configuration. Thus, I want to define completly different files for such working cases.

Currently I have `application.properties` for local porpouse, and `application-tst.properties` to be use in Heroku. But I don't know how to pick the proper one when deploying.

My goal is to have different configuration for my app running in Heroku than the one running in my local machine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can control which profile is active using the `spring.profiles.active` property ([documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles)). On Heroku you can set this using config vars either via [the cli, the dashboard](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars) or the [platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars)

### CLI

For setting the `tst` profile using the cli, try

```
$ heroku config:set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=tst
```

### Dashboard

Navigate to the `settings` tab and set key as `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` and value as `tst`, then click `save`.

### Platform API

You could use several tools to achieve the same result, but following the Platform API documentation, you could use `curl`

```
$ curl -n -X PATCH https://api.heroku.com/apps/$APP_ID_OR_NAME/config-vars \
  -d '{ "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE": "tst" }' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

Be aware though that setting the `spring.profiles.active` property as a config var will affect the whole application.

Comment: how did you find out, that Heroku uses SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE env variable for setting `spring.profiles.active` property, please?

Comment: The documentation, really. Spring Boot [profiles doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles) describes how to set active profiles using env variables. The javadoc for [SystemEnvironmentPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.html) describes how it resolves env variables. The heroku doc explains how to set [their equivalent of environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), `config vars`