# How to manage multiple Spring profiles with Heroku

Tags: java, spring, git, heroku, azure-devops

I'm setting up a new environment for my application, we only have "prod" environment, I want to create a testing environment, for that, I configured two Spring profiles, "test" and "prod", and created a new branch called "test" where we want to have the test environment and push that branch to master like a kind of "promotion" to production.
This is a extract of our `application.yml`

```
spring:
  profiles: test
 {some properties...}

---

spring:
  profiles: prod
 {some properties...}
```

We are using Heroku to deploy our app and repositories from AzureDevOps, where we also have a pipeline that runs when we push commits to master, this pipeline push the AzureDevOps master branch to the Heroku repository. In Heroku we have an application created on "staging", we didn't add a "production" application yet (not sure if it's relevant but I wanted to clarify that).

This is the pipeline:

```
git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)
git remote add heroku https://heroku:$(pat)@git.heroku.com/app-hto.git
git push heroku $(Build.SourceBranchName)
```

To specify the profile I'm using the `Procfile` file in my Java project, where we have this:

```
web: java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

As you can see I'm not a Heroku expert so I don't know how to proceed, so, my question is, how can I specify which profile use for each environment? There is a way to accomplish that using AzureDevOps pipelines?

Comment: You would normally have some kind of default `application.yml` and load another yml like `application-${spring.active.profile}.yml`. You can do this with multiple [@PropertySource annotations](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/) to load the default yml and override the defaults with the profile specific property values. It supports SpEL so you can access the active profile in it

Comment: @Marco Marchetti Did you tried to use Heroku to set the spring.profiles.active property mentioned in below thread?

Comment: Actually I can't, we are on a code freeze until today's afternoon, so I will try that approach tomorrow and will let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Devops might be able to accomplish that, but it would be complicated.

It will be easier to achieve this with heroku. Heroku itself provides ways to control which profile is active either by cli, dashboard,or api. for details check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984799/deploy-spring-boot-app-to-heroku-with-a-particular-application-properties-file)

Hope i point to the right direction.